# How to turn JSON return value into a table?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm very confused on how to handle a JSON return value.
I use this code to retrieve it:

```
$.post('php/testphp.php', 'clickBtnValue=' + $(this).val(), function(response) {});
```

I get back this response:

```
[{
  "firstname": "Zach",
  "0": "Zach",
  "lastname": "Alber",
  "1": "Alber",
  "dojo": "Okinawa",
  "2": "Okinawa"
}]
```

Comment: read on `.each()`

Comment: What output are you expecting to have? Your returned object seems to have repeated values in the numeric keys - is that intentional?

Comment: what you want to do with response ?
 like display in page or what ? @Zachariah

Comment: Sorry to get back to you guys late. What I'm looking for is to put this into a table. I know I only have one row in my database. I'm going to add more later. I'm going to display this all in a table on my website.

Comment: I figured it out everyone. I did this: var parsed = JSON.parse(response). There I'm able to do do parsed[0].firstname  and access it. I'm turning the values into a table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON before you can access it as an object...

```
$.post('php/testphp.php', 'clickBtnValue=' + $(this).val(), function(response) {

      var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
      alert(parsed[0].firstname);

});
```

Why is this needed? It's because JSON is not JavaScript. The two terms are not synonymous.

JSON is a textual data interchange format. It needs to be parsed into the data structures of whatever language it's been given to. In your case, the language is JavaScript, so you need to parse it into JavaScript data.

Comment: When I try it your way I get an undefined in the alert.

Comment: @ZachariahAlber edited my answer. missed array notation for parsed!

Answer (score 0):

The way to do that is to have your call like the following:

```
$.post('php/testphp.php', 'clickBtnValue=' + $(this).val(), (function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    this.object_var = response.data;
}).bind(this));
```

Once you print the response object you will see what you have in there. In many cases your response object will be stored inside `response.data`.

Additionally if you want to assign the value to some variable outside of your `post` request object, you can either `.bind(this)` the object, or simply define a variable outside it like the following:

```
var my_var;

$.post('php/testphp.php', 'clickBtnValue=' + $(this).val(), function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    my_var = response.data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Please check snippet , this may help you to resolve your issue

```js
$(function() {
var jsonData = [{
  "firstname": "Zach",
  "0": "Zach",
  "lastname": "Alber",
  "1": "Alber",
  "dojo": "Okinawa",
  "2": "Okinawa"
}];

for(var i=0; i <= jsonData.length; i++)
{
  var fname = jsonData[i].firstname;
  var lname = jsonData[i].lastname;
  var dojo = jsonData[i].dojo;
  
  var table = '<table border="1 px"><tr><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Dojo</td></tr><tr><td>'+fname+'</td><td>'+lname+'</td><td>'+dojo+'</td></tr>' ;
  document.write(table);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

First parse with JSON.parse() then access them like an object. Example:

var obj = JSON.parse(your_data);

then

obj[0].userID